# Extract a disjoint collection of intervals almost covering $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Think of $[0,1)$ as a circle with the endpoints $0$ and $1$ identified. In $[0,1)$,fix an interval $[a,b]$ of very small length $\epsilon:=b-a>0$. Take an irrational $\alpha$. Since $\{n\alpha\pmod 1\}$ is dense in $[0,1)$, $\bigcup_n [a\oplus n\alpha,b\oplus n\alpha]=[0,1)$ where $x\oplus y :=x+y\pmod 1$ when both $x,y\in[0,1)$.

Given $\delta>0$, can I find mutually disjoint collection of intervals $[a\oplus n_k\alpha,b\oplus n_k\alpha]$ for some sequence of positive integers $n_k$ such that $Leb\left(\bigcup_k [a\oplus n_k\alpha,b\oplus n_k\alpha]\right)>1-\delta$? It is intuitively clear to me this can be done, that is finding a disjoint union of such intervals almost covering $[0,1)$. But the way this can be done, is evading me. Any help is appreciated.

The way I proceeded was, try greedily. But it's a bit hard to keep track of where the intervals will end up.

Comment: Please note, I can choose $\epsilon$ based on $\delta$. The $\epsilon$ can be really small.

Comment: Do you mean $Leb(\bigcup_k[a\oplus n_k\alpha,b\oplus n_k\alpha]) > 1 - \delta$?  And presumably the sequence $n_k$ is a finite length sequence?

Comment: does the intervals have to be of this specific form? Or cancit be something like $[a\oplus n_k\alpha,b\oplus n_{\lambda}\alpha]$?

Comment: Yes Stephen, the sequence $n_k$ should be finite, since each such interval has the same finite positive length and you cannot have infinitely many disjoint such intervals in $[0,1]$. @alphaomega they have to be of this specific form.

Comment: Did you try choosing $n_{k+1}$ so that $0 < (a-b)\oplus (n_{k+1}-n_{k}) \alpha < \eta$ where $\eta$ is very small?  That way the successive intervals are in order, and very close to each other.

Comment: Sorry Stephen, I don't quite follow your comment. But I couldn't think of anything so structured. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The idea is that you choose $n_{k+1}$ so that $a\oplus n_{k+1}\alpha$ is slightly to the right of $b \oplus n_k \alpha$, but no further than distance $\eta$ from it.

Comment: But also, you didn't answer the first part of my first comment.  I think you might have a typo in your question.

Comment: Oh yes yes, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$, and $[x]$ denote the integer part of $x$.  Let $I_n = [\{a + n\alpha\}, \{ b + n\alpha\}]$ (with obvious modifications in case we 'wrap around,' that is, $\{ b + n\alpha\} \le \{ a + n\alpha\}$).

Pick $\epsilon,\eta > 0$ to be chosen later.  Suppose we have chosen $n_1,\dots,n_k$.  By density, we can find an $n_{k+1} > n_k$ so that $\{a + n_{k+1}\alpha\} \in (\{b + n_k \alpha\}, \{b + n_k \alpha\} + \eta)$.

Then the intervals $I_{n_1}, I_{n_2}, \dots, I_{n_K}$ are disjoint if $K(\epsilon+\eta) < 1$.  Choose $K = [ 1/(\epsilon+\eta) ]$, so $K(\epsilon+\eta) > 1-\epsilon-\eta$.

Then
$$ \text{Leb}\left(\bigcup_k I_{n_k}\right) = K\epsilon > 1 - \epsilon - (K+1) \eta > 1 - \epsilon - (1/\epsilon + 1) \eta .$$
So choose $\epsilon < \delta /2$ and $\eta < \delta/(2(1/\epsilon+1))$.

Comment: I see what you were saying. Thank you!